# Why am I getting an "Access Denied" error when trying to open a repository in R Studio from Github Desktop?

Tags: r, github, github-desktop

I am trying to open a repository in an external editor (R Studio) using Github Desktop. I am able to successfully clone a repository and get to this point:

[image]

When I try to open in R Studio, I get the following error:

[image]

I am able to pull, push, and commit directly in R Studio without any problems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess the first questions that come to mind are 1. which specific file is it opening, and 2. is there some kind of permission issue with Github Desktop opening it?